# Microsoft-Graph: Invoke-MgGraphRequest returns unable to cast object of type JsonObject to JsonArray

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use *Invoke-MgGraphRequest* to convert immutableEntryIds to ewsIDs. I have been following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell) and have created the following PowerShell script:

```ps1
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions
$params = @{
    InputIds = @(
        "{<my immutable EntryID 1>}",
        "{<my immutable EntryID 2>}"
    )
    SourceIdType = "immutableEntryId"
    TargetIdType = "ewsId"
}

Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $params
```

Running this script results in the following error:

```
Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.Json.JsonObject' to type 'Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Runtime.Json.JsonArray'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId -UserId $userId -BodyParameter $para ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-MgTransl...geId_Translate1], InvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.InvokeMgTranslateUserExchangeId_Translate1
```

I have seen similar errors for other [MgGraph commands](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/665) that are open issues on Github. Has anyone been able to get the Invoke-*MgTranslateUserExchangeId* command without this error occuring?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue with Invoke-MgTranslateUserExchangeId but you should be able to work around it using Invoke-MgGraphRequest eg

```
Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/translateExchangeIds" -Body $params -Method POST
```

Its bug in PowerShell module something to do with the way their auto generation code works so you might want to create a issue in gitHub.